# Precompilation breaking on heroku, works locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, less

I did some restructuring of our less files. Everything works locally (e.g. `rake assets:precompile`), but on Heroku my push fails with the following:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
       adding placeholder
       rake aborted!
       Less::ParseError: variable @brand-primary is undefined
       (in /tmp/build_24298d78-579f-44a3-ae43-c4d82b9dde9d/app/assets/stylesheets/lectures/lectures.less)
       at /tmp/build_24298d78-579f-44a3-ae43-c4d82b9dde9d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/less-2.5.1/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:604:31
```

After much poking around, I decided to remove the import statement for the offending file (lectures.less) to see what breaks next. With the change committed and pushed to Github, I tried pushing again to Heroku, and got the exact same error -- the precompilation is now breaking on a file that shouldn't be imported any more.

Details pasted below; anyone got any tips? I've tried both `heroku run rake assets:clean` and `heroku run rake tmp:clear`, but I didn't expect them to work anyway.

My application.css is barebones:

```
...
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require main
 */
```

PREVIOUSLY I was requiring the lectures file and some others in application.css, but moved it into the main.less.

My main.less has the rest of the imports:

```
@import "settings";
@import "variables";
...
@import "lectures/lectures.less";
...
```

Relevant environment settings:

development.rb

```
config.assets.precompile                           += %w( admin.js admin.css )
config.less.dumpLineNumbers                        = 'all'
config.assets.debug                                = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.raise_runtime_errors                 = true
```

staging.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.js admin.css )
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

relevant gems:

```
ruby '2.1.2'
gem 'rails', '>= 4'
gem 'less-rails', github: 'metaskills/less-rails'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We appeared to have fixed the issue by bumping the config.assets.version setting in production.rb, e.g.

```
- config.assets.version = '1.0'
+ config.assets.version = '1.1'
```

It's not clear in the slightest to me why heroku didn't recognize the changes and why `heroku run rake assets:clean` didn't do it, but there you go.

EDIT #################
It's been a while since this, and to keep from having the issue on a regular basis, we wound up tying the version # to our commit sha. Something like this:

## whatever.rb

```
heroku = Heroku::API.new(api_key: ENV['HEROKU_API_KEY'])
$asset_version = heroku.get_releases(ENV["HEROKU_APP_NAME"]).body[-1]["commit"]
```

## production.rb

```
config.assets.version = $asset_version
```