# Errno::ENOENT: No such file or director config/settings.yml (heroku deploy)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I am trying to deploy to heroku and getting the following error, which is below. I would appreciate any tips or help on solving that please.

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/config/settings.yml
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/settingslogic-2.0.9/lib/settingslogic.rb:102:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/settingslogic-2.0.9/lib/settingslogic.rb:60:in `new'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/settingslogic-2.0.9/lib/settingslogic.rb:60:in `instance'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/settingslogic-2.0.9/lib/settingslogic.rb:48:in `load!'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/app/models/settings.rb:4:in `<class:Settings>'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/app/models/settings.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:480:in `load_missing_constant'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/config/initializers/action_mailer.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:379:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
   /tmp/build_c6574b00-1f27-48f0-a3ea-4413871d028e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
   Tasks: TOP => environment
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

config/settings.yml is as below ///////////////////////////////

```
defaults: &defaults
core:
name: My_app
smtp:
  default_from:
  host: 
  port:
  domain:
  username:
  password:
  authentication:
  start_tls:

development:
<<: *defaults
web:
host: localhost:3000

test:
 <<: *defaults
web:
host: localhost:3000
```

Comment: Do you have `settings.yml` file included in your version control system (git) as generally `.yml` files are not included in git. Also such variable are not set via yml on heroku. They set via environment variables. You can find detail here http://tammersaleh.com/posts/managing-heroku-environment-variables-for-local-development/

Comment: Is this solution ? So I can move it to answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following post helped
[Precompilation breaking on heroku, works locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165395/precompilation-breaking-on-heroku-works-locally)

Just change config.assets.version

- config.assets.version = '1.0'
- config.assets.version = '1.1'

Answer (score 1):

I think that your file is not included in your git repository. Try

```
git add config/settings.yml
git commit -m 'adding settings'
git push heroku master
```

It should work
and make sure to change config.assets.version

- config.assets.version = '1.0'
- config.assets.version = '1.1'

Comment: Is the 'rake assets:precompile' task working in local ?

Comment: Was that the solution ? If it was I will change my answer for people who might need it.

Comment: i was using this doc here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline, but trying to precompile locally  `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` gave me an error => `Settingslogic::MissingSetting: Missing setting 'production' in config/settings.yml`, so I suppressed this in production [doc] (https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic#5-suppressing-exceptions-conditionally), so running it now precompiles it okay in public/assets as in doc. I add it to git `git add public/assets - A` and `git commit -m "vendor compiled assets"` then `git push heroku master`

Comment: but it still gives me the same error as in my original question? Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have a production.rb file in your config/asset directory?

Comment: I don't have config/asset directory at all? I have config/environments where I have the file there

Comment: okay, this allowed me to push to heroku - config.assets.version = '1.0'
+ config.assets.version = '1.1', but i still have no pictures/icons there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62245/discussion-between-mariekou-and-igor).